# React-Native How to pass and access data inside an array of array from props

Tags: arrays, react-native, state, react-props

I am trying to: 
1) Create an array of objects, one of the object is another array of objects
2) I want to pass the data from parent (array created) to child component to render out the data inside the array

Following is my Parent component dealList.js of created array:

```
constructor(){
const array = [
            {
                title: 'Picture Max ',
                dealId: 12345,
                publishDate: '14 Sept',
                status: 'Good',
                position: 'Manager',
                sub_Category: [{
                    firstTime: '6:00pm',
                    tableTitle: 'Guidance',
                    company: 'Capcom',
                    tableDetails: [
                        [
                            '53',
                            'CT5+Area',
                            'Benchmarking'
                        ],
                        [
                            'afa445',
                            '3mL 3fmjer',
                            '300'
                        ],
                        [
                            '7Y',
                            '4.3 - 434 Area',
                            '200'
                        ],

                    ]

                }]

 this.state = {

            AccordionData: [...array]


        };

}

//Passing array as props to child component function 
renderDealBoards() {

        return (
            this.state.AccordionData.map((item, key) =>

                (
                    <DBDetails key={item.title} 
                                      item={item}/>

                ))
        );
}
```

Following is my Child Component DBDetails.js

```
this.props.item.tableDetails.map((item, key) => (

       <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
           <Row data={this.state.tbHead} style={styles.tbHead}                       textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
 <Rows data={item} textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
      </Table>
           ))
```

However, when i run the code there is this error code:

```
TypeError: TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined
```

Can anyone help me out in what went wrong and how do i overcome this because i am new to react-native and just coded recently.

Comment: can you add two logs in Child Component's constructor or render method... console.log(typeof this.props.item.tableDetails) and console.log(this.props.item.tableDetails)

Comment: @JaydeepGalani the console returns 'undefined'

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are referring this.props.item.tableDetails.map but your tableDetails are inside the sub_Category property which is also an array. So you should use sub_Category.map(x=>x.tableDetails.map(//somecode here)) to map the itableDetails which is inside the sub_Category.

Comment: this.props.item.sub_Category.map((item, key) => (
                                        item.tableDetails.map(
                                      
                                                <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
                                                    <Row data={this.state.tbHead} style={styles.tbHead}
                                                         textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
<Rows data={item} textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
 </Table>))

Comment: There is an error that says: TypeError: # <Object> is not a function

Comment: the initial problem with the map should be fixed by the above answer, the <Object> is not a function normally occurs when using exports in a wrong way check that

Comment: How about this error means: TypeError: data.map is not a function?

Comment: probably you are calling the map function on an object instead of an array

Comment: this.props.item.sub_Category.map((item) => (
                                        item.tableDetails.map(x =>(
             <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
              <Row data={this.state.tbHead} style={styles.tbHead}
  textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
 <Rows data= {x} textStyle={styles.tbText}/</Table>))))

Comment: Currently i am doing what u has said and it returns me typeerror: data.map is not a function. But when i console.log the x value it is perfectly fine that list out all the elements in tableDetails array

Comment: what happens inside Rows ?

Comment: it returns that type erro: data.map error message on this line: 
<Rows data= {x} textStyle={styles.tbText}/>

Answer (score 0):

Pass item.sub_category see this,

```
   <Table borderStyle={{borderWidth: 2, borderColor: '#c8e1ff'}}>
     <Row data={this.state.tbHead} style={styles.tbHead} 
          textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
     <Rows data={item.sub_Category} textStyle={styles.tbText}/>
    </Table>
```

Comment: Im trying to access tabledetails array inside sub_category